# AngularJs controller get request not hitting Spring MVC Rest Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

So I have my angular javascript as

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/core/students.json')
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.user = data;
                });
    });
```

and my rest controller with

```
@RestController
public class StudentRestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/students", produces = { "application/json" }, method =      RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Student getStudent() {
    // return studentService.getStudentByUserName(userName);
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setUserName("userName");
    s.setEmailAddress("email");
    return s;
}
}
```

but for some reason, the javascript ajax request isn't hitting the method getStudent(). Why is this? I get a console error

```
"GET http://localhost:8080/core/students.json 404 (Not Found)"
```

ordinary button url calls work as expected

Answer (score 1):

change angularjs app as

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller', [ "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/students").success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    });
} ]);
```

that holds if ur `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name> dispatcherServlet </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern> * </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "/students" on the @RequestMapping, then your URL should be ".../core/students".